# Reading in line by line from a file with different variable types

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fault

For a project I'm doing we have to populate a queue with "House" objects.  The "House" objects get their information from a file called "data.dat".  Each line of the file is another thing that goes into the house object.  So first I take a char* for the address, then an int, another int, a third int, and then another char*.  We aren't aloud to use strings to get the char* variables which I believe is where I'm running into my problem.  Every time I compile it tells me I have a segmentation fault.  Here is the area of my queue.cpp that I'm pretty sure the error is in

```
#include"queue.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<istream>

Queue::Queue(const char *filename){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    std::ifstream infile(filename);

    char * address = NULL;
    int footage = 0;
    int bedrooms = 0;
    int bathrooms = 0;
    char * features = NULL;

    while(!infile.eof()){
            while(infile.get() != '\n'){
                    //std::cout << infile.get(); 
                    infile.get(address[i]);
            }
            infile >> footage >> bedrooms >> bathrooms;
            while(infile.get() != '\n'){
                    infile.get(features[i]);
            }

            enqueue(House(address, footage, bedrooms, bathrooms, features));
            }
    infile.close();
```

}

Here is the house object header file:

```
    House();
    House(char * ad, int fo, int be, int ba, char * fe);
    char * getAddress();
    int getFootage();
    int getBedrooms();
    int getBathrooms();
    char * getFeatures();

    void setAddress(char * ad);
    void setFootage(int fo);
    void setBedrooms(int be);
    void setBathrooms(int ba);
    void setFeatures(char * fe);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, House& house);

private:
    char * address;
    int footage;
    int bedrooms;
    int bathrooms;
    char * features;
```

};

Comment: and data.dat looks like...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `features`  and `address` first, either by using `new` or by creating it as array of chars of some length.
The way you do it you're trying to write to the memory that was't assigned yet - hence buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's a cleaned up version

- mainly it replaces `char*` with `std::string` (since we're doing C++)
- it makes the whole thing self-contained.
- It uses correct input validation (don't use `while (!infile.eof())`, check extraction operators)

I didn't implement your Queue :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0befd62d1279c89a)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct House {
    House()
        : address(), footage(0), bedrooms(0), bathrooms(0), features() 
    { }
    House(std::string ad, int fo, int be, int ba, std::string fe) 
        : address(ad), footage(fo), bedrooms(be), bathrooms(ba), features(fe) 
    { }

    std::string getAddress()   const { return address;   }
    int         getFootage()   const { return footage;   }
    int         getBedrooms()  const { return bedrooms;  }
    int         getBathrooms() const { return bathrooms; }
    std::string getFeatures()  const { return features;  }

    void setAddress(std::string  ad) { address   = ad; }
    void setFootage(int          fo) { footage   = fo; }
    void setBedrooms(int         be) { bedrooms  = be; }
    void setBathrooms(int        ba) { bathrooms = ba; }
    void setFeatures(std::string fe) { features  = fe; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, House const &house) {
        return out << "Address: "      << house.getAddress()   << '\n'
                   << "Footage: "      << house.getFootage()   << '\n'
                   << "Bed rooms:   "  << house.getBedrooms()  << '\n'
                   << "Bath rooms:   " << house.getBathrooms() << '\n'
                   << "Features: "     << house.getFeatures()  << '\n';
    }

  private:
    std::string address;
    int         footage;
    int         bedrooms;
    int         bathrooms;
    std::string features;
};

struct Queue {
    Queue(std::string  filename);

    struct Node {
        House value;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node *head, *tail;

    void enqueue(House const& h) {
        // TODO
        std::cout << h << "\n";
    }
};

Queue::Queue(std::string filename) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {

    std::ifstream infile(filename);

    std::string address;
    int footage = 0;
    int bedrooms = 0;
    int bathrooms = 0;
    std::string features;

    std::string line; // lines

    while (getline(infile, address) && getline(infile, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        if (iss >> footage >> bedrooms >> bathrooms && getline(iss, features)) {
            enqueue(House(address, footage, bedrooms, bathrooms, features));
        }

    }
}


int main()
{
    Queue q("data.dat");
}
```

For input:

```
Blv. Dreams Abroken 24, 78377d XG, ClassyCode
2 4 1 pool sauna porch indoor-parking
Oyi. Qernzf Noebxra 24, 78377q KT, PynfflPbqr
3 8 2 cbby fnhan cbepu vaqbbe-cnexvat
```

It prints the output:

```
Address: Blv. Dreams Abroken 24, 78377d XG, ClassyCode
Footage: 2
Bed rooms:   4
Bath rooms:   1
Features:  pool sauna porch indoor-parking

Address: Oyi. Qernzf Noebxra 24, 78377q KT, PynfflPbqr
Footage: 3
Bed rooms:   8
Bath rooms:   2
Features:  cbby fnhan cbepu vaqbbe-cnexvat
```